# Communication between cluster nodes

Tags: weblogic, cluster-computing

I am looking for an effective way to communicate between several cluster nodes (for application coordination). As it stands database is not an option.

Is it possible to use the unicast channel to transmit the message? Do i need to use JMS Topics? or directly open sockets on each node ?

Edit: as for usage, it's for application coordination, deciding which node does what.

Comment: Can you give an example of the intended usage? Is it to update some properties or clear cache data or soemthing else?

Comment: Can you give a more detailed example of a use case?

Comment: You've written it is to decide "which node does what"? Will this be controlled by some central logic at runtime or triggered manually on the respective server by the application support group.

Answer (score 0):

JMS can be an option if your application can stand async communications between nodes. The clustered JNDI tree can be a very good option also, the weblogic cluster will take in charge its replicaion among cluster nodes for you.
Another very common approach is to use an in-memory database or a distributed cache to share data between nodes.

Comment: In terms of JMS i cannot determine which node grabs the message, so i would be totally dependent on wls cluster node balancing. might be a interesting solution. It's been a while since i've thought of this. Currently using http to communicate between nodes, which pretty much sucks.